# Betta fish appears to struggle to swallow food pellets

Tags: fish, diet, feeding, betta

I recently acquired a Betta fish. I also purchased "standard" Betta fish food pellets. My Betta fish does try to eat the food, but sometimes appears to struggle to swallow the pellets. I can see the pellets partway outside of its mouth for awhile before it swallows the pellets. Recently, it was even trying to eat new food pellets before even "fully" swallowing the pellet that was in its mouth at the time.

Is this normal, or is there some kind of problem? How can I ensure that my Betta gets sufficient nutrition?

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, is there any reason why you couldn't switch to food in flakes?

Comment: @lila I could if that's the consensus for the best solution. I'd like to know whether what I was noticing is a problem or not first, though.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarification, I cannot reliably give you an answer because I never used pellets, only flakes. But I'm sad that nobody, nobody, nobody else came to give their input about this :/

Comment: I have no betta, but some fish of different size in one tank. I use to press the pellets until they crumble, so the smaller fish take the small crumbles and the bigger ones the bigger parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it ended up not being a problem. After a couple of weeks, he's now grown to the point of being able to swallow the pellets easily.